# Prettier adding a new line for ">." (html)

Tags: html, prettier

I have the following html:

```html
<div>
    Some text
    <strong><a routerLink="/button">update now</a></strong
    >.
</div>
```

Prettier autoformats the `>.` to a new line. Why is this? Is there a rule to change it?

If I add a space between the angled closing bracket and the full-stop then it looks as I'd expect:

```html
<div>
    Some text
    <strong><a routerLink="/button">update now</a></strong> .
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is just the weird way prettier formats this, what I usually do is just add a  linebreak after `<strong>` and before the `</strong>` when using prettier but tbh i just switched to using eslint as a formatter because of this behaviour.

Comment: In Prettier Preferences, set HTML wihitespace sensitivity to 'strict'

Answer (score 0):

adding:     `"htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"` to `.prettierrc` fixes it.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity